# xcode won't build examples in Cocoa Programming 4th ed

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm getting errors and warnings that seem to indicate that 4th edition examples are meant for OSX 10.7 and xcode 4, but I'm using OSX 10.6 and Xcode 3.2.

I already edited Project Settings to set Xcode 3.2 but continue to get these errors when I try to build Typing Tutor. I have no idea where to look for fixes. This is my first try; presumably the same types of errors will occur when I try other examples.
How do I fix Xcode settings for all of them? Is there an errata file somewhere, which would include my problems?

Nick

```
ERRORS and WARNINGS:

COPY OF "BUILD FAILED" :

Check dependencies

[WARN]Deployment target 10.7 for architecture 'x86_64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value 10.6 for the Mac OS X 10.6 SDK.

error: unknown property attribute 'strong'
@property (strong) NSColor *bgColor;
^
warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed
@property (strong) NSColor *bgColor;
^
warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

nnickk

Posts: 1
Joined: Sat Dec 31, 2011 10:19 pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project is probably using ARC (Automated reference counting) which is only available in OS X 10.7 and iOS 5+. The project may also be using storyboards for UI which means you would have to use Xcode 4 and iOS 5. To get rid of those error though you would convert those properties from strong to retain and probably put nonatomic in as well if it's not a property you use in other threads.

```
@property (retain) NSColor *bgColor;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is relatively straightforward, but much more complex is the long list of warnings saying that xcode 4 libraries can't be found. I was hoping that there is a straightforward recipe for getting these examples to compile and run under xcode 3.2 and OSX 10.6. Maybe I'll have to copy from those examples, paste into new 3.2 projects, and redo the Interface Builder connections. Laborious and error prone!